# Is there any way to prevent domain models from populating in the view model list in add view dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that consists of three projects. The projects are:

- mywebapp.datalayer (class library)
- mywebapp.domainmodels (class library)
- mywebapp.webui (ASP.Net MVC application)

Inside my MVC project I have a folder named view models where all my viewmodels go.

Inside my controllers I have references to my two other projects to get data and then use Automapper to map domain models to view models.

The problem I have is that when I use the Add View dialog in Visual Studio and wish to create a view based upon a model, it populates it's drop down list with both my domain models and my view models. Is there any way to restrict this list to only classes from my viewmodels folder or similar approach?

Comment: Maybe I just don’t understand your question, but what’s the problem with that? It’s just presenting you a choice between all the available entities in your application. Eventually, you’re allowed to only present one model in your view

Comment: For my understanding , you can add different name for model name , viewmodel name , You can use what you want.

Comment: Yes the problem is having domain models and view models show up as duplicates. So you have UserFormModel and UserFormViewModel options in the add view dialog where I only want UserFormViewModel class to be an option. This isn't a problem in small applications but when you have over a hundred views it gets overwhelming.

Comment: You can try postfixing your Viewmodels with VM or ViewModel at the end if you want that separation, or just remove reference to your other two class projects and add all the view and only add them back as soon as you are done adding views